# Angular2 custom attribute for css selector

Tags: html, css, angular, css-selectors

I'm trying to set a custom attribute in a div so that my css selector can find it. But I can't find the right syntax.

css:

```
 div[customAttr="dabadeedabadie"] {
    color:blue
 }
```

html:

```
<div customAttr="dabadeedabadie">I'm blue</div>
```

That works, but if I try with angular:

```
<div customAttr="{{'dabadeedabadie'}}">I'm blue</div>
```

I get an error: **Can't bind to 'customAttr' since it isn't a known property of 'div'**. Well... right but why is that a problem ?

I also tried :

```
<div attr.customAttr="'dabadeedabadie'">I'm blue</div>
<div attr.customAttr="{{'dabadeedabadie'}}">I'm blue</div>
<div [attr.customAttr]="'dabadeedabadie'">I'm blue</div>
<div [attr.data-customAttr]="'dabadeedabadie'">I'm blue</div>
```

Those don't throw an error but don't work either.

How can I set a custom tag property recognized by the css selector with angular ?

Answer (score 2):

[It works both of ways](https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-vjp8ux?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

using parameter in ts and with hard coded

```
<div [attr.customAttr]="'dabadeedabadie'">I'm blue</div>
<div [attr.customAttr]="name">I'm blue with param</div>
```

TS

```
 name = 'dabadeedabadie';
```

CSS

```
 div[customAttr="dabadeedabadie"] {
    color:blue
 }
```